# Read base64 contents in a file with other texts

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, base64

I have a `mytext.txt` file and its contents as follows:

```
...
I 07/06/2022 10:26:19:301 y2031211                  doing| deleting data for now with 0: function: 122, uname: <hidden>, upass: <hidden>
I 07/06/2022 10:26:19:301 y2031211                  doing|    Reg req: M = [P] URI = [https://myURIxxxxx.com/mb/nr/action] BODY = [parameters=bl64lI2hMI8/u+OUQfYmUw83/0lJ/2s2sGaEl2ycy/mtiIf6nC9G5I2OwDHw
lh/Ds22ScsXdugLeLL0sqq5KSZyRaScv/Nk3/sWUSPEzDDibmXEW3t/qGJ39
k5qIBypH0KS8EcSnPg/CPHgH44Uzi1VBZZwai4TUj26IOWOYKD7HpasZXf1k
5hz8WQfxeC2iz9RFV27GEabyzgu9+OK3c9ffVjplO5QFo10nCefarXcLlbiT
sBKpeyk9jQ9/3rh++UM83ZVzAegzsmgQ4tLfkmV2ou6Kl7gNm9w28DGp8Mnf
ZXFTw4REddcZA2jMxQOIHE92wYSy5bDVfoIADnUqSQ==
]

T 07/06/2022 10:26:19:302 y2031211                  doing| still have active session but no data ready at this time; waiting...
T 07/06/2022 10:26:19:548 y2031211              done| creation
T 07/06/2022 10:26:19:549 y2031211              done| connect
T 07/06/2022 10:26:19:549 y2031211          done| connection succeeded to myURIxxxxx.como:443
...
```

the above is an excerpt of a `txt` logfile and I wanted just to read out the `base64` contents of the `parameters`. the file was too large and contained so long lines but I presented that as sample.

so far I did this:

```
with open('mytext.txt', 'r') as handle:
            lines = handle.readlines()
            
            for line in lines:

                if "parameters=" in line:
                    print("\n")
                    print(line[line.index('parameters=')+11:])
                    print("\n")
```

but this only `outputs` `bl64lI2hMI8/u+OUQfYmUw83/0lJ/2s2sGaEl2ycy/mtiIf6nC9G5I2OwDHw` but what I'm trying to do is that to get the entire `base64` contents as an output as like this:

```
bl64lI2hMI8/u+OUQfYmUw83/0lJ/2s2sGaEl2ycy/mtiIf6nC9G5I2OwDHw
lh/Ds22ScsXdugLeLL0sqq5KSZyRaScv/Nk3/sWUSPEzDDibmXEW3t/qGJ39
k5qIBypH0KS8EcSnPg/CPHgH44Uzi1VBZZwai4TUj26IOWOYKD7HpasZXf1k
5hz8WQfxeC2iz9RFV27GEabyzgu9+OK3c9ffVjplO5QFo10nCefarXcLlbiT
sBKpeyk9jQ9/3rh++UM83ZVzAegzsmgQ4tLfkmV2ou6Kl7gNm9w28DGp8Mnf
ZXFTw4REddcZA2jMxQOIHE92wYSy5bDVfoIADnUqSQ==
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use regex to split by the actual log lines, and clean up the text.

```
import re
import base64
with open('content', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()

lines = re.split(r'I [0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9][0-9]', content)

for line in lines:
    if 'BODY = ' in line:
        print('body detected')

        tmp_split = line.split('BODY = ')
        tmp_split = tmp_split[-1] # select last element
        tmp_split = tmp_split.replace('\n', '').replace('\r\n', '') # delete new lines
        tmp_split = tmp_split[1:-1] # remove starting and ending bracket

        base64_str = tmp_split.replace('parameters=', '')
        print(f'BASE64:\n{base64_str}\n')

        decoded_bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_str)
```